# retrieve multiple row xml data to dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to return multiple rows from xml data. I have loaded the result into a dictionary. The code below gives me the last result (row 1 or Randy). How do I retrieve all of the results instead of just the last one? I'm looking for CSHR_POS_NAME where [ID.text intValue] == CSHR_NUM.

```
dict = [resp objectForKey:@"TC"];
 if( ( dict == nil ) || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
  NSLog( @"WARNING: %@", [dict description]);
  return;
}

desc = [[dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_POS_NAME"]copy];
CashierNum = [[dict objectForKey:@"CSHR_NUM"]copy];

NSLog(@"Name: %@ and Cashier Number: %@",desc, CashierNum);
```

the log for the xml output is:

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
  <TC diffgr:id="TC1" msdata:rowOrder="0">  
    <CSHR_POS_NAME>BRITTANY</CSHR_POS_NAME>
    <CSHR_NUM>66</CSHR_NUM>
  </TC>
  <TC diffgr:id="TC4" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <CSHR_POS_NAME>Randy</CSHR_POS_NAME>
    <CSHR_NUM>7</CSHR_NUM>
  </TC>
</NewDataSet> 
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an array of dictionaries with the `"TC"` key. Should you not be trying to read the response as an array, and then iterate through the dictionaries?

Comment: I agree with mundi, if you're adding dictionary objects with the key @"TC" over and over again, you're essentially rewriting each entry  as you go... This would make it so that the only value you can retrieve is the last one (i.e. Randy)

Comment: Thanks, Guys. I'll give that a try. I assume I do the same basic dictionary stuff with an NSArray instead?

Comment: I think it's a sudzc problem.  It loops through the deserialize overwriting the previous node.  The array won't work.